# Postgres pgp.multi query execution, keeping track of which rows are a result of what query

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, pg-promise

I'm trying to use the Postgres DB npm package pg-promise `multi` method for the ability to run multiple queries.

The queries are user inputted.

An example is below.

```
const queryArray = [
    {
        query: "SELECT * FROM credentials_entities WHERE type = 'public'",
        values: {}
    },
    {
        query: "SELECT * FROM credentials_entities WHERE type = 'shared'",
        values: {}
    }
];

const cleanedAndConcatQueries = pgp.helpers.concat(queryArray);
const result = await db.multi(cleanedAndConcatQueries);
```

I want to embed a column inside each query execution to simply keep track of which query the results came from.

My original thought was to wrap the query in a CTE dynamically.
It only works for 1 query at a time understandably, but not for x queries.

```
    const queryArray = [
        {
            query: "SELECT * FROM credentials_entities WHERE type = 'public'",
            values: {}
        },
        {
            query: "SELECT * FROM credentials_entities WHERE type = 'shared'",
            values: {}
        }
    ];


    const dynamicQueries = queryArray.map((value, i) => {
        let {query} = value;
        query = `
            WITH query_${i} AS (${query}) 
            SELECT 
                ${i} as new_embedded_column, // new column with query index
                *                            // original values from user inputted query
            FROM query_${i};
        `;
    });
    
    
    const cleanedAndConcatQueries = pgp.helpers.concat(dynamicQueries);
    const result = await db.multi(cleanedAndConcatQueries);
```

Is there some way to accomplish this via my current approach or via another method?
To re-iterate, I want to keep track of which query resulted in what results.

Comment: "*It only works for 1 query at a time understandably, but not for x queries.*" - how so? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Because of the way CTEs work, where when creating more than one you have to join it with the previously created in order to continue to gather all of the information in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, at the moment, I found a solution that definitely does not require or involve wrapping the queries in a CTE.

The detail is that the result @ [0] of the multi-query call is an array of results from query @[0].
[pg-promise multi doc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi)

```
const [users, products] = await db.multi('SELECT * FROM users;SELECT * FROM products');

const queryResults = await db.multi(pgp.helpers.concat(queries));
return queryResults.map((query, index) => {
    // here we have the query and its index where index-0 is from query[0]
    // so this allows me to keep track of the results 
    // & which query they are a result from
});
```